# Request.GetOwinContext fails in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I try to get OWin working following that popular tutorial on a Web Api:
http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/

Now I got stuck on the following Getter:

```
  protected AppliationUserManager TengoUserManager
        {
            get { return _applicationUserManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); }
        }
```

The problem is that Request.GetOwinContext() always returns null.

**When I change the getter to**

```
    get { return _applicationUserManager ?? System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); }
```

**everything works fine.** Now I wonder:

*Is there any disadvantage in using `HttpContext.Current` instead of `Request`?*

As the `HttpContext` has the OwinContext(), but the `Request` hasn't: Is this solvable by configuration? The Startup-Code for my Owin-Authentication is:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   HttpConfiguration httpConfig=new HttpConfiguration();            

   app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationContext.Create);
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
   app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
   app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Comment: Try moving app.UseWebApi after app.CreatePerOwinContext(*) - the Use* statements typically compose middleware.

Comment: did that. No change. Updated the question

Comment: Did you find a solution @Shelakel? I'm needing it...

Comment: I didn't, I changed the company and so also the project. :)

Comment: same issue for me. I enabled cookie authentication and its worked fine. I added app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()); this to ConfigureAuth method of owin startup class